# BCL.Async issue with F# project

Tags: f#, nuget, base-class-library

Using the latest VS2013, if I create a clean console application and add a nuget reference to BCL.Async, all colouration in VS dies. You then get: -

"Internal language services have encountered severe errors. Syntax coloring or other features may stop working. If you experience such issues, they could be fixed as follows: (1) Clean current solution (2) Restart Visual Studio (.."

Needless to say neither works.

Comment: Worked for me VS 2013 Update 4, Project settings: .NET 4.5, F# 3.1 (FSharp.Core, 4.3.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is repro-ed when the project targets .NET 4.0 but not when it targets .NET 4.5.

To be clear, the error message originates from Visual F# Power Tools (see https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/blob/bc76dc272cb941fdbc04e2a0d203a685c5d3bc84/src/FSharpVSPowerTools.Logic/Resource.fs#L55). What happened is that [FSharp.Compiler.Service](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service) chokes on newly-added assemblies and throws exceptions to upper layers.

When I installed `Microsoft.BCL.Async` from NuGet package console, there are some installation errors. So I had to manually add references to `System.Data`, `System.ServiceModel` and `System.ServiceModel.Discovery` so that the project can be compiled. When the project is compilable, colorization goes back in normal.

That said, the error message could be improved to avoid being so horrifying though.

Comment: cool, i'll check that out. How did you figure out to add those three assemblies?

Comment: Eh, I tried to compile. The Error List told me which assembly is missing, one by one.

Comment: OK, I got an error with System.Threading.Tasks.dll - once I added that it worked.